# Library Mode with Vite 4 and Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to create a component library using Vue 3 and Vite 4, with Vite's "Library Mode".

I followed the steps described in https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode .

My component library (which actually, just for testing purposes, has just one simple component: MeuCompo.vue) is at https://github.com/carlospauluk/minha-biblioteca

I performed the build with "yarn build" and published it on npmjs.com (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@carlos.pauluk/minha-biblioteca).

Then I tried to build my app, also with Vue 3 and Vite 4 (it's at https://github.com/carlospauluk/meu-vue3vite4-app).

But, when I try to run with "yarn dev" I get the following error:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@angular/core"

     node_modules/my-library/fesm5/my-library.js:1:66:
       1 │ import { Injectable, Component, NgModule, defineInjectable } from '@angular/core';
         ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   You can mark the path "@angular/core" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove
   this error.

/home/carlos/dev/github/meu-vue3vite4-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1636
   let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
...
..
.
etc etc etc
```

What am I missing here?

I tried to add this "@angular/core" in the...

```
rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue', '@angular/core'],
```

... but it doesn't make any difference.

Here in my dev env I have node v16.19.1, yarn 1.22.19 and npm 8.19.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it normal after installing the lib that it doesn't have any nodes_modules ? I mean, I've made a lib too and when I install it, it has her own nodes_modules folder. Maybe I'm missing something. And also the link to your lib isn't correct

Comment: I think the links were wrong. Correcting now, sorry!

Comment: Now the links are ok. If you can, just clone it and run yarn install. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I caught an error `the requested module 'minha-biblioteca.js' does not provide an export named 'MeuCompo'`. I must be precise that I'm working in link mode.